# How to make Post operation using .net core and neo4j

Tags: c#, asp.net, neo4j, neo4jclient

I am very new at .Net Core and Neo4j. I want to make Wep Api for CRUD operations using Neo4jClient.I have a Book class and its controller. Also I have Author and its controller class. I want to make Post operation,but I cannot. Postman returns BadRequest(). So How can I solve this? What is the problem?

**Here is my source code for Book.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NEO4j.Models
{
    public class Book
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public List<string> CategoryCodes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**BookController.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using NEO4j.Models;
using NEO4j.Services;
using Neo4jClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NEO4j.Conrollers
{
    [Route("api/book")]
    public class BookController : Controller
    {
        private static int uniqueId=1;
        public string title { get; set; }
        public List<string> category { get; set; }

        private static BookService bookService;
        private static CategoryService categoryService;

        static BookController()
        {
            bookService = new BookService();
            categoryService = new CategoryService();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Get()
        {
            var graphClient = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"), "neo4j", "1234");
            graphClient.Connect();

            var data = graphClient.Cypher
               .Match("(m:Book)")
               .Return<Book>("m")
               .Results.ToList();

            return Ok(data.Select(c => new { book = c }));
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Post([FromBody] Book book) {

            var client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"), "neo4j", "1234");
            client.Connect();


            if (book == null)
                return BadRequest();

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest(ModelState);

            var newBook = new Book { Id = uniqueId, Title = title, CategoryCodes = category };
            client.Cypher
                .Merge("(book:Book { Id: {uniqueId} ,Title:{title},CategoryCodes:{category}})")
                .OnCreate()
                .Set("book = {newBook}")
                .WithParams(new
                {
                    uniqueId =newBook.Id,
                    title = newBook.Title,
                    category = newBook.CategoryCodes,
                    newBook
                })
                .ExecuteWithoutResults();

             uniqueId++;
             return Ok(newBook);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to add your Postman request details, and specify where "bad request" comes from - your API or your call to external API (neo4j)...my _initial guess_ points to `null` for `book` (?).

Comment: @EdSF  http://localhost:63654/api/book  {"Title":"Deep Learning",   "CategoryCodes": "5"} . When I made debug book is null and graphClient.cs cannot be found. But it is installed.

Answer (score 1):

Only for the ASP.Net Core part:

> localhost:63654/api/book {"Title":"Deep Learning", "CategoryCodes": "5"}
>
> `book` is null

1. *How* you make your request (in your case, `Postman`) matters - which is why I asked you to provide. So `Headers` and such are important.

   Sending `JSON`via Postman:

   ```
   POST /api/test HTTP/1.1
   Host: localhost:63654
   Content-Type: application/json       
   Cache-Control: no-cache
   Postman-Token: 51081616-c62d-c677-b5ab-37d428018db5

   {"Title":"Deep Learning", "CategoryCodes": ["1","2","3"]}
   ```

   **Note the `Content-Type` Header**
2. `CategoryCodes` in  our `Book` model is a `List`, so you have to set a "list" (array) for its value as shown above `"CategoryCodes": ["1","2","3"]`

Hth..